# Sending email via SendGrid after form submission

Tags: sendgrid, svelte, sveltekit

I'm putting together a contact form using Svelte and SendGrid. Here is a basic app.svelte:

```
<script>
    import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';
    sgMail.setApiKey(import.meta.env.VITE_SENDGRID);

    function submitForm() {
        const msg = {
            to: 'test@example.com',
            from: 'test@example.com',
            subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
            text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
            html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>'
        };
        console.log('Form submitted');
        sgMail.send(msg);
    }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={submitForm}>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The code above does not send an email after the user selects `submit` on the form, despite the function being called (it logs `Form submitted` in the console). When I move all code from `submitForm()` outside the function, the code executes on page load, so I know it's not an issue with my API key.

Any suggestions what I am missing?

Comment: Try moving `sgMail.send(msg)` one line above and see if it logs the success message again. And, are there any errors showing up in the console?

Comment: @Kalyan It looks like `Form submitted` is not logged when I move `sgMail.send(msg);`. If it helps, I noticed that when I moved `const msg = { .. }` outside the function I was able to get console to log `Form submitted`.

Comment: @R Barnes I'm not so familiar with the Send Grid API, but it seems `sgMail.send()` is not being executed or throwing an error. Earlier, as you placed 'console.log` above `send(msg)`, the message will be logged even if `send()` is not called.

Comment: `sgMail.send(msg).then(() => {}, error => { console.error(error); if (error.response) { console.error(error.response.body) }});` Try this so that any errors from sendmail api will be logged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Svelte is a frontend environment only. The Sendgrid package is desinged for a server side / node.js environment. In your example, your Sendgrid API key would be exposed because you're trying to use it on the frontend / client side.

A solution may be to look at SvelteKit, which has the concept of 'endpoints' which always run on the server side. Or you can create an express server to handle the sending of email to Sendgrid.

EDIT: The solution is to use Sveltekit endpoints. Endpoints always run on the server. Your final solution may look something like this:

File: /src/routes/api/sendmail.ts or /src/api/sendmail.js

```js
import sgMail from "@sendgrid/mail";
sgMail.setApiKey(import.meta.env.VITE_SENDGRID);

export async function get(page) {
      const msg = {
        to: "test@example.com",
        from: "test@example.com",
        subject: "Sending with SendGrid is Fun",
        text: "and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js",
        html: "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>",
      };
      console.log("Form submitted");
      const output = await sgMail.send(msg);
  return {
    body: output,
  };
}
```

File /src/routes/index.svelte

```js
<script>
  function submitForm() {
    fetch("/api/sendmail");
  }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={submitForm}>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That makes sense, it looks like it's a CORS issue - interesting that Safari console didn't mention that but Chrome did. I'm currently using SvelteKit, do you know of any resources that share how to do this?

Comment: I was busy writing a solution based on SvelteKit. One moment

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this. I ran the code from your example and placed the script in `/src/api/sendmail.js` but console says `GET http://localhost:3000/api/sendmail 404 (Not Found)`. Would you happen to know what could be causing this issue?

Comment: You should be able to access the route if you browse directly to it in your browser. http://localhost:3000/api/sendmail. Does that work? What SvelteKit adaptor are you using?

Comment: I get a `Not found: /api/sendmail`, specifically at resolve, at processTicksAndRejections, async Object.handle, async respond, and async file. I was using adapter-auto then moved to adapter-node.

Comment: I think I found the problem! I ran into problems if I placed it in `/src/api/sendmail` but it worked when I used `/src/routes/api/sendmail.js`. Would you happen to know why that's the case? Thank you for the help regardless!

Comment: All the routes need to go into the /src/routes/ folder. I may have ommited that by mistake.

Comment: Didnt you all faced an issue with `require not defined` when import @sendgrid/mail?